# Two different archive pages showing the same content

Tags: custom-post-types, ajax, archive-template

I'm trying to use [Query Multiple Taxonomies](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/query-multiple-taxonomies/) with Ajax. 
It works with Ajax and it works without it. But unfortunately not at the same time.
Basically I need an Archive page to show only the posts of my custom post type "filme" (to insert it with ajax) and another Archive page with the menue, header etc. to use it with the basic Query Multiple Taxonomies, if Javascript is disabled.

I've already tried to create a page and an empty custom post archive and "convert it" by using a function hooked to 'pre_get_posts()' but without any luck.

The problem is Query Multiple Taxonomies seems to need the main-query to work.
I hope it's clear what I'm trying to do, It's a bit comprehensive.

EDIT: I've tried to load the archive-page inside itself with AJAX too, but it was incredible slow, so I guess it's not the right way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution. Maybe it could help someone else.

In my archive-filme.php I just used the basic loop:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>  
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
         get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
     endwhile; ?>
<?php else : ?>
     <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'none' ); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Now I use a page with an custom-template. In the content-div I placed 
`include get_bloginfo( 'url' )'/filme/?' . urldecode( $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"] )`
The query_string, cause I need to pass some GET-variables to the page.

For the ajax solution I used the checkboxes provided by Query Multiple Taxonomies and loaded the archive-filme.php into my content-div, again with the get variables.
I'm really not sure if this weird text can help someone, but I hope so.